# How to handle the history-back to reload the whole page on the client side, without using Ajax at the "popstate" event?

Tags: javascript, jquery, browser-history, html5-history

I'm trying to perform a history-back to reload the whole page on the client side, and every example I have seen so far uses Ajax to reload the content in a page's <*div*>. And it doesn’t serve me because I need to change the header too.

I also have an additional difficulty to deal with. In my case, I have to push the state both in links' click events and when a modal window is opened, which is actually a <*div*> that goes to nowhere.

I have tried the following:

```
$(function() {

    $(window).on("popstate", popStateHandler);

    // initial state
    window.history.pushState( { pageContent: "<html>" + $("html").html() + "</html>" }, location.href, location.href);

    $("a").click(function (e) {

        var pageUrl = $(this).attr('href');

        if (pageUrl != window.location) {
            window.history.pushState( { pageContent: "<html>" + $("html").html() + "</html>" }, pageUrl, pageUrl);
        }

        // I don't avoid links' navigation
    });
});

var popStateHandler = function(e) {

    var stateData = e.originalEvent.state;

    if (stateData) {
        // it replaces the page's content with the one stored into the history
        $("html").html(stateData.pageContent);
    }
};

var loadModalWindowContent = function (url, contentLoadedEvent) {

    if (!isEmpty(layerModalWindowContainer_ContentObj) && url) {


        if (url != window.location) {
            window.history.pushState( { pageContent: "<html>" + $("html").html() + "</html>" }, url, url);
        }

        layerModalWindowContainer_ContentObj.load(url, function () {

            // it shows the modal window <div> when the content is loaded into it
            layerModalWindowContainerObj.css("display", "");

            if (contentLoadedEvent) triggerEvent(contentLoadedEvent);
        }); 
    }
};
```

As shown above, I push the state at “ready” event, storing the whole page’s content, and I define the same behavior on links’ “click”, as well as in the function below that opens the modal window.

Then, I define a “popstate” handler function, which will be called when history-back is performed. And inside it, I replace the page's content with the one stored into the history.

Sadly it doesn’t work properly, because though the page’s content is loaded, its javascript isn’t.

I have also tried other ways to reload the page, such as carrying out a "location.reload();" (which is supposed to use the browser’s cache by default) and a "location.href = stateData.pageURL;" (storing that URL previously on "pushState"), but somehow there is always something wrong in the result.

I hope you can help me, or at least show me how this should work.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Maybe I've misunderstood, but have you tried a simple `history.back()`? Here's a definition; http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/met_his_back.asp

Comment: Yes I did, but the thing is, if I go back to the main page, which is the one that has the modal window inside, it just reloads the modal window’s content, perhaps because of the pushstate performed when it is opened, but if I do not push the state, the whole page is reloaded from the server side… this is the quandary.

Thank you anyway for your help.